# design issue with stored procedures

Tags: c#, asp.net, database-design, stored-procedures

i am building some sort of content system.

anyway i have a database with 3 tables
lets say one is for news and the others for articles and stories.

now i want to make a service which backups only articles who are going to get edited.
anyway i want all the logic in the asp.net and not in the database itself.

anyway my problem starts here: the stored procedures i have that inserts new articles which i want to use inserts those articles to the tbl_articles table
and now i want to use my buisness layer which uses my data layer
that calls that stored procedure to insert backed up articles to a table called
tbl_articles_backup

now i see i have a design problem... maybe if i have thought about this feature in the past when i started i would of used something else like linq or something like that in my data layer.

now my question is : what can i do in oreder to still get the best design i can without changing the all program.
i dont want to duplicate the same stored procedure.. and i dont want to just overload the methods in the buisness layer and the data layer.

any ideas?..
whats my best option?

thanks

Comment: Is this just for data archiving of original versions of edited articles?  If so, this sounds like a job for a trigger, unsexy as that may be.

Comment: i thanks for the comment. will its more complex then that... i need a backup of just changed stuff in the current day i have a service which syncs the enviorment where pepole edit articles doring the day. to the production enviorment i want to make the backup seervice run just before the sync service. so ill have a backup of stuff getting changed..

Answer (score 1):

I think a trigger is your best choice.   Anytime the table gets updated it can insert the same row into your backup table.   This is automatic and guaranteed to run during your transactions.

Its not really that hard.  In the end if you write your logic in VB or SQL you will still need to learn LINQ or SQL commands.   I personally recommend trying to keep the database logic in the database and simplify the asp.net side of things.

If you give us a copy of the insert SP I can show you how to write the update trigger.

Answer (score 0):

"anyway i want all the logic in the asp.net and not in the database itself.

...

whats my best option?"

Well, if you are already decided that you want your logic outside of the database, then whatever 'options' you are asking for, are merely just asp.net options and definitely not database/dbms options, and you had better remove any of those 'database' tags.